# Credit Card Charged Twice After Place Order in Magento 2.2.9

Tags: payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway, credit-card, magento2.2.9

We are using the CardConnect Payment Gateway for our site. Before a few days ago we face a credit card charged two times for some `orders` and Magento Shows only 1 order and 1 Invoice and 1 transaction. So we have asked CardConnect Support team and they replied like below:

```
software sending the requests to our gateway multiple times. Please check below the snapshot for the same.
```

[image]

[image]

We have checked the `logs` and found that there is a double `authcode` for those orders.

In the CardConnect Configuration, we have set `"Action"`: `Authorize & Capture`. We have also placed test orders but we can not reproduce the issue. 
Can anybody suggest me how to solve this kind of issue? Below is the `Model` File snapshot for the Payment for the reference.

For `Authorize` Function :

```
$data = [
            'merchid' => $merchantId,
            'accttype' => $payment->getCcType(),
            'account' => $additionalInfo['cc_number_enc'],
            'expiry' => str_pad($expiryMonth, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . substr($expiryYear, -2),
            'cvv2' => $payment->getCcCid(),
            //'amount' => $amount * 100,
            'amount' => $grandTotal * 100,
            'currency' => $order->getBaseCurrencyCode(),
            'orderid' => $order->getId(),
            'name' => $billing->getName(),
            'address' => $billing->getStreetLine(1),
            'city' => $billing->getCity(),
            'region' => $billing->getRegion(),
            'country' => $billing->getCountryId(),
            'postal' => $billing->getPostcode(),
            'email' => $billing->getEmail(),
            'phone' => $billing->getTelephone()
        ];

        if ($capture) {
            $data['capture'] = 'Y';
        }
```

For `Capture` Function:

```
// If we have previously captured an amount, we need a new auth token, otherwise use the one we had.
        $order_total_due = $order->getBaseTotalDue();
        if ($order_total_due != $order_total) {
            $billing = $order->getBillingAddress();
            $authorize_data = [
              'merchid' => $merchantId,
              'account' => $additionalInfo['token'],
              'expiry' => $additionalInfo['cc_expiry'],
              'amount' => $amounttax * 100,
              'currency' => $order->getBaseCurrencyCode(),
              'orderid' => $order->getId(),
              'name' => $billing->getName(),
              'address' => $billing->getStreetLine(1),
              'city' => $billing->getCity(),
              'region' => $billing->getRegion(),
              'country' => $billing->getCountryId(),
              'postal' => $billing->getPostcode(),
              'email' => $billing->getEmail(),
              'phone' => $billing->getTelephone(),
            ];
```

Order status for double-charged is under `"Processing"` state and Invoice state is `paid`. 
Regular order status is under the "Payment Review" state and the Invoice state is `" pending"`.

While checking `Order` under the `Sales > Orders` we can see a comment like below for the Regular orders:

```
An amount of $3.28 will be captured after being approved at the payment gateway.
```

For Double Charged like below:

```
Captured amount of $3.69 online. Transaction ID: "070459346166"
```

Can anybody take a look into this to solve this issue? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an issue with the server. I have this exact issue, but when I changed my cron jobs to once daily, versus every 5 minutes, the problem went away. You may want to look into optimizing your site/server, or moving to a new host.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this may be related to MySQL issue, let's check the log first.
My case is, this MySQL error log appear near the time that the issue orders happens:

> Aborted connection 1198255 to db: '...' user: '...' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)

Then I did follow this guide to make it fixed: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19139